# How to use iframe to show another website?

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, plugins, jquery-plugins

web page is loading without any errors, but When I click on the button to load the iFrame nothing happening. Can anyone tell me how to fix it in WordPress, is their any plugin to solve this problem.

Comment: It will be great to edit your post with more details like stating clearly the expected click behaviour and or error you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have wrong double `<script>` wrapping:

```
<script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      ...
```

And you don't have click button handler. So you can't get any reaction after click.
Also you have a weird part "  .product-list" at URL. What do you want with it? 
Maybe you are looking for smth like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            $('#fetch-btn').click(function () {
                jQuery("#div1").load("any-url");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1" class="product-list"></div>

<button id="fetch-btn">Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

But it still cannot load whole foreign site content to your div. You should use iframe for it. And you should read about [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) and try use any proxy with your domain for it.
Did it help you?

Answer (score 1):

try to use an iframe,if you want to interact with the inner website

Answer (score 1):

you can not download data from another site.
uses a simple proxy written in PHP!

```
echo (file_get_contents($_POST['url']));
```

and use jQuery!

```
$.ajax({
  url: "./your_proxy.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    url: 'https://www.youtube.com'
  },
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(data) {
    var d = $(data); // your data
  }
});
```